# vi shortcut to delete "until the next X character"

Tags: vim

I understand that vi has shortcut keys to delete characters, words and lines with various options.

However, I could not find this:

- delete from the cursor to the next specified character

For example, I might type `du"` expecting the editor to "delete until the next `"` character is found"

The closest I know is `d9w` where `9` is the number of words to delete.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: If you're interested in Vi and Vim, they have their own SE site now: [vi.se]

Answer (score 452, accepted):

Use <kbd>dt</kbd><kbd>*c*</kbd>, where *c* is any character, e.g. for you, you want <kbd>dt</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

This will delete upto but **not** including *c*.

If you had:

```
delete until exclamation point!
```

And the cursor was at the first space and you typed <kbd>dt</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>, you would get:

```
delete!
```

Also <kbd>df</kbd><kbd>*c*</kbd>.

This will delete upto **and** including *c*.

Using <kbd>df</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> on the same example above would give you:

```
delete
```

Just about any "motion" can be used for the `d`, `c`, `y` and similar commands.

Comment: Presumably the mnemonic is t for "till"? Nice answer.

Comment: You can also delete to the previous instance of a character with the capitalized version of the movement commands. Maybe more useful for commas -- `dT,` and `dF,`.

Comment: This doesn't work over multiple lines.

Comment: Anyone know of a nice summary of these commands? What do `c` and `y` do?

Comment: You can look at some of the cheat sheets.  One good page seems to be http://www.cse.psu.edu/~deh25/cmpsc311/Instructions/vi.html;  `c` changes/replaces lines, 'y' yanks/copies lines, 'p' prints/pastes.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the `df`, or "including" the last char.

Comment: Can this be done over a range of lines?

Comment: For doing something similar over a range of lines, a usual search (as in zpletan's answer) can be performed: `d/word` searches up to `word`. It must be followed by enter (to close the search).

Comment: one way to do this over a range of lines is to use a macro; for example, suppose you want to delete from the beginning of the line (0 to go to beginning of line) up to the first comma for 10 lines starting with the current line; step (1) make the macro, named 'a', (q starts and stops macro input, can contain many vi commands) type this:   qa0dt,q  step(2) run the macro 'a' for 10 lines, type this: @10a

Comment: So easy:

`ctJ` = "change till 'J'" – erases from the cursor position through the first 'J' on the line and leaves you in input mode to type its replacement

Answer (score 87):

- To delete forward up to character 'X'  type <kbd>dtX</kbd>
- To delete forward through character 'X'  type <kbd>dfX</kbd>
- To delete backward up to character 'X'  type <kbd>dTX</kbd>
- To delete backward through character 'X'  type <kbd>dFX</kbd>

Comment: You can also add a number after the `d` character to delete through multiple instances.
For example with the cursor at column 0 `d2f!` whould delete forward up through the second instance of the `!` character on the line.

Answer (score 30):

The input dt# (not a :command, use it like a movement like G)

will delete from the cursor until but not including the #. You can substitute any char for #.

Comment: This is the right answer! df# will delete # as well.

Comment: been looking for this, this is awesome

Answer (score 21):

It looks like @Arcege already answered the question, but I did `d/l` to delete until the character `l`; other characters would work as well.

Comment: This works for stuff across newlines.

Comment: Note: this must be followed by Enter.

Comment: d?l to delete backwards

Answer (score 7):

`w` moves to the following word. `l` moves to the following charactor.

So it's `d9l` to delete the next 9 characters.

Comment: Close, `l` is Vim's right arrow key, so you're actually deleting right. Conversely, `d9h` would delete 9 characters left.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest use `delete with pattern`,

`d/<pattern>`

**d** is action delete

**/** is vim searching sign

for example, the following is a MySQL connection string. I want to change to the password `redhat` to new one

`root:redhat@tcp(localhost:3306)/?parseTime=True`

In command mode , I click `w`(skip to next word), the cursor move to ":", click `w` again will move the cursor to first char `r` of password `redhat`. now click `d/@` will delete the any characters until `@` that in this case will remove the `redhat`. `d/@tcp` is better if the string has more than one `@`, the pattern more paticular is more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned about that so I thought I would share this as well.
If you want to delete until a character you can use `dt` and type the desired character. If you want to delete until a character but the character is also in the middle for instance `(hell(o) world)` and you want to delete from `hell(o)` until the last `)` and your cursor is on the `h` you can type a number, in this case `2dt)` this will jump the first `)`.

You can also use `de` (delete end), here by "end" you have to think "end of the word (not line)" so if you want to delete for instance `.world` in `(hello.world)` and your cursor is on the dot, you can type `de`.

Hope it helps

Comment: For your example just use `di)` to delete inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `ct"` instead of `dt"` do delete until `"` and also enter insert mode, that is, `dt"i` == `ct"`